# Changing automatically value on range fields

Tags: javascript, html

I have three range fields with a total percentage of 100. The idea is for those three fields to communicate with each other and has a total value of 100%. That's working fine.

While you drag the range field, the label value is increasing/decreasing for that specific field but not for the other two.

The result should be that while you increase/decrease one range field, the other two increase/decrease their label value as well.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tcL1nkj0/), and once you see it, you will see the issue.

```js
const els1 = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.pp-ranges'));
const total1 = 100;

const values1 = new Array(els1.length).fill(40);
els1.forEach((el, i) => el.value = values1[i].toFixed(3.3));

const handleChange1 = e => {
  const changedIndex = els1.indexOf(e.target);
  const newValue = +e.target.value;
  values1[changedIndex] = newValue;
  const otherIndexes1 = new Array(els1.length)
  .fill(0)
  .map((_, i) => i)
  .filter((_, i) => i !== changedIndex);

  const otherSum1 = otherIndexes1.map(i => values1[i])
  .reduce((a, c) => a + c);

  if (otherSum1 === 0) {
    otherIndexes1.forEach(i => values1[i] = (total1 - newValue) / (values1.length - 1));
  } else {
    const f = (total1 - newValue) / otherSum1;
    otherIndexes1.forEach(i => values1[i] *= f);
  }
  els1.forEach((el, i) => el.value = values1[i].toFixed(2));
}
els1.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('input', handleChange1));

document.querySelector("#ppBearInputId").addEventListener("input", function (e) {
  document.querySelector(".pp-label-beer-range").textContent = e.currentTarget.value;
})
document.querySelector("#ppVineInputId").addEventListener("input", function (e) {
  document.querySelector(".pp-label-vine-range").textContent = e.currentTarget.value;
})
document.querySelector("#ppStrongInputId").addEventListener("input", function (e) {
  document.querySelector(".pp-label-strong-range").textContent = e.currentTarget.value;
})
```

```html
<div class="pp-fields pp-m-tb-10 pp-inline-flex">
    Pivo<input id="ppBearInputId" type="range" class="pp-ranges" name="ppBearInputName" value="40" min="1" max="100"/><label class="pp-label-beer-range" for="ppBearInputId">40</label>%
</div>
<div class="pp-fields pp-m-tb-10 pp-inline-flex">
    Vino<input id="ppVineInputId" type="range" class="pp-ranges" name="ppVineInputName" value="35" min="1" max="100"/><label class="pp-label-vine-range" for="ppVineInputId">35</label>%
</div>
<div class="pp-fields pp-m-tb-10 pp-inline-flex">
    Žestina<input id="ppStrongInputId" type="range" class="pp-ranges" name="ppStrongInputName" value="25" min="1" max="100"/><label class="pp-label-strong-range" for="ppStrongInputId">25</label>%
</div>
```

Comment: Managing the moving parts of data reactiveness is the first use case that prompts people to shift towards a front end framework, to leverage two way data binding. I would recommend Vue for its simplicity and usability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct solution is to select the label closest to each input range and set its value to the same thing as the input range:

```js
els1.forEach((el, i) => {
  el.value = values1[i].toFixed(2);
  el.parentNode.querySelector("label").textContent = el.value;
});
```

Now there are some rounding errors to consider, but it's not quite clear how that should be resolved to match your specifications, so I'll leave that open as a separate issue.

```js
const els1 = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.pp-ranges'));
const total1 = 100;

const values1 = new Array(els1.length).fill(40);
els1.forEach((el, i) => el.value = values1[i].toFixed(3.3));

const handleChange1 = e => {
  const changedIndex = els1.indexOf(e.target);
  const newValue = +e.target.value;
  values1[changedIndex] = newValue;
  const otherIndexes1 = Array(els1.length)
    .fill(0)
    .map((_, i) => i)
    .filter((_, i) => i !== changedIndex);

  const otherSum1 = otherIndexes1.map(i => values1[i])
    .reduce((a, c) => a + c);

  if (otherSum1 === 0) {
    otherIndexes1.forEach(i => values1[i] = (total1 - newValue) / (values1.length - 1));
  } else {
    const f = (total1 - newValue) / otherSum1;
    otherIndexes1.forEach(i => values1[i] *= f);
  }
  els1.forEach((el, i) => {
    el.value = values1[i].toFixed(2);
    el.parentNode.querySelector("label").textContent = el.value;
  });
}
els1.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('input', handleChange1));

document.querySelector("#ppBearInputId").addEventListener("input", function (e) {
  document.querySelector(".pp-label-beer-range").textContent = e.currentTarget.value;
})
document.querySelector("#ppVineInputId").addEventListener("input", function (e) {
  document.querySelector(".pp-label-vine-range").textContent = e.currentTarget.value;
})
document.querySelector("#ppStrongInputId").addEventListener("input", function (e) {
  document.querySelector(".pp-label-strong-range").textContent = e.currentTarget.value;
})
```

```html
<div class="pp-fields pp-m-tb-10 pp-inline-flex">
    Pivo<input id="ppBearInputId" type="range" class="pp-ranges" name="ppBearInputName" value="40" min="1" max="100"/><label class="pp-label-beer-range" for="ppBearInputId">40</label>%
</div>
<div class="pp-fields pp-m-tb-10 pp-inline-flex">
    Vino<input id="ppVineInputId" type="range" class="pp-ranges" name="ppVineInputName" value="35" min="1" max="100"/><label class="pp-label-vine-range" for="ppVineInputId">35</label>%
</div>
<div class="pp-fields pp-m-tb-10 pp-inline-flex">
    Žestina<input id="ppStrongInputId" type="range" class="pp-ranges" name="ppStrongInputName" value="25" min="1" max="100"/><label class="pp-label-strong-range" for="ppStrongInputId">25</label>%
</div>
```